# Database is in compatibility range and upgrade is recommended

Tags: database

In my farm I installed the SharePoint 2013 directly, and I didn't had any older SP system in the farm. I am not sure why i get the following error message :

> The following databases have versions that are older than the current SharePoint software, but are within the backwards compatible range: 
>   User Profile Service Application_SocialDB_20d62230387b4b18991716b7896792f4,
>   Search_Service_Application_1_AnalyticsReportingStoreDB_db835a5a161e495590d0e283430221d9,
>   Bdc_Service_DB_9d59366e2e4940119caa56c8792f028a,
>   SP13,
>   SettingsServiceSPDB,
>   Search_Service_Application_1_CrawlStoreDB_38f3c806e741422b9d270a5611b43d3c,
>   App_Management_18842f54-177d-410d-96d0-481d776ef9e3,
>   AppMng_Service_DB_5cc2693c68d142c395ad51c187e1e0a8,
>   CapricornSPAppService,
>   SharePoint_AdminContent_292ef3b7-a8a4-4790-94f4-3e9d54a01376,
>   WSS_Content,
>   Search_Service_Application_1_DB_596d3871154a4f48811ecbd2db37119a,
>   User Profile Service Application_ProfileDB_0cc698283c514281abe9d15559839b76,
>   WSS_Logging,
>   Search_Service_Application_1_LinksStoreDB_b1b76508974c4aa2a0f189773c0cffd2.

Every topic online that I was able to find talks about some step of migrating from 2010 to 2013 which isn't my case.

Why does this happen and how can I get rid of it?  Remember that I did not upgrade from SP2010.

Comment: Did you install a new 2013 farm? Did you install 2013 on a existing 2010 farm? I don't really understand what you have done to be honest.

Comment: more information required otherwise no body can anwser it....1) how you install the SP2013? Did you use any 2010 DB in 2013 farm? did you apply the CU and run the Config wizard? how many server in farm?

Comment: It was the first time I was installing it. All databases are created by SP13. 3 servers in the farm. Normal installation procedures followed.

Answer (score 0):

You will get this message

> The following databases have versions that are older than the current SharePoint software, but are within the backwards compatible range

when upgrading SharePoint 2013 with patches or updates.

You can check this in the CA under "Update and Migration" / "Database Status" (_admin/DatabaseStatus.aspx). Run `PSCONFIG.EXE -cmd upgrade` to update most of the databases. Some may be updated by PowerShell `Upgrade-SPContentDatabase`.

Answer (score 0):

Run SharePoint Configuration Wizzard or PSConfig. It will upgrade all databases. When you install SharePoint updates or language updates on servers in farm, you have to run PSConfig always to upgrade databases and SP farm.

> PSConfig.exe -cmd upgrade -inplace b2b -wait -cmd applicationcontent
> -install -cmd installfeatures -cmd secureresources -cmd services -install

*Hope it helps!*

*Mark answer as accepted solution, if it works.*